# How do I install Quantum ESPRESSO on Linux?

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, software, molecular-modeling, software-assistance

People, can someone please help me how to solve this problem with QE 7.0 installation:

[image]

Comment: It must be sudo apt-get install gfortran

Comment: I was writing wrong, however, I already installed the Fortran compiler, before trying to compiler QE.

Comment: Actually, I think that the error is something related to the source code, because there are messages about "Array Specification".

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? If yes, can you try installing quantum espresso from the ubuntu repository?

Comment: Allocating with only `mold` is a 2008 feature, most likely your gfortran version does not support the f2008 standard. I would start there.

Comment: How can I solve it?

Comment: With posting code or terminal input/output, it is almost always better to post it as a formatted code block rather than an image: https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/411/why-do-we-ask-you-to-use-code-blocks-rather-than-screenshots

Comment: I agree with Tyberius, please remove the screenshot and post the information in a `code` block instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As suggested in the comment, you can use ubuntu repository to install them:

```
$ sudo apt install quantum-espresso
$ sudo apt install wannier90
```

If you get prompted for a password or yes/no confirmations, proceed accordingly. However, this would install a slightly earlier version of QE and you will not have full control over it. As you already probably trying to install it from the source code (guessed from the comment), the following is the easiest I believe. First you need the following libraries:

```
git wget g++ gfortran liblapack-dev libfftw3-dev libopenmpi-dev
```

To install them, do:

```
$ sudo apt install git wget build-essential
$ sudo apt install g++ gfortran liblapack-dev
$ sudo apt install libfftw3-dev libopenmpi-dev
```

Then you are ready to download and compile the source code. To download the latest version:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/QEF/q-e.git
```

Then first enter the downloaded folder (it's name should be q-e or q-e-# where # is the version number) and then run configure:

```
cd q-e
./configure
```

Lastly, you can install everything or parts of Quantum ESPRESSO by the `make` command.

```
make all
```

will do everything. But if you want just pw.x (or post-processing stuffs), then do `make pw` (or `make pp`). Sometimes the wannier90 installation fails, but everything else works. You will get the binaries in the bin folder. To use the binaries directly from anywhere, you need to export their path:

```
$ echo 'export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/q-e/bin' >> ~/.bashrc
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

Here I assumed that your q-e folder is in the home (~) directory. If it is in some other directory, change the path from `$HOME/q-e/bin` to that directory (for example `$HOME/Downloads/quantumespresso/qe-7.0/bin`). Hope it helps.